# Processing 3 - Cannot insert .svg

Tags: svg, vector, processing

I'm trying to enter an .svg using loadShape and it says "the variable 'head' does not exist. My files are in my data folder, I'm not sure what's going on. Here's my code:

```java
// global stuff - variables



//setup routine - only runs once at the very beginning of your sketch
void setup()  {
   head=loadShape("head.svg");
   size(500, 500);
   background(0);
   noStroke();
   smooth(); 
}  

//draw routine - runs over and over again forever
void draw()  {
   background(200);
   shape(head, width/2, height/2, 475, 475);
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code that calls your `setup` and `draw` functions? Where is the declaration of `head`? Is it implicitly declared by usage (and so being global) or is it declared somewhere else?

Comment: @JoachimSchirrmacher Please notice that this is a [tag:processing] question. See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java) for more info.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Thanks, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all: you're never **declaring** the `head` variable, so it doesn't exist.

See the comment at the top that says `// global stuff - variables`? You need to declare your `head` variable there. To declare a variable, you give it a type and a name. In this case, the type is `PShape` and the name is `head`:

```
PShape head;
```